# Codepen to be modified

Tags: javascript

I have this CodePen in which I'm interested:

```
https://codepen.io/rachsmith/pen/PWxoLN
```

The problem is that the JavaScript code only considers that each card will have the same text when it expands, and the text is contained in the code.

The author mentions that it is just an exercise and I quite like the fact that this work does not rely on any external sources.

So how can I change the code so that the correct text is assigned to the card that was clicked?

Consider that I'm planning to have two cards only. This is what I tried on the function that injects the text inside the card text field:

```
function animateCoverUp(card) {
  // get the position of the clicked card
  var cardPosition = card.getBoundingClientRect();
  // get the style of the clicked card
  var cardStyle = getComputedStyle(card);
  setCoverPosition(cardPosition);
  setCoverColor(cardStyle);
  scaleCoverToFillWindow(cardPosition);
  // update the content of the opened page
  if (cards[0]) {
  openContentText.innerHTML = '<h1>'+card.children[2].textContent+'</h1>'+paragraphText0;
  openContentImage.src = card.children[1].src;
  } else if (cards[1]) {
    openContentText.innerHTML = '<h1>'+card.children[2].textContent+'</h1>'+paragraphText1;
    openContentImage.src = card.children[1].src;
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    // update the scroll position to 0 (so it is at the top of the 'opened' page)
    window.scroll(0, 0);
    // set page to open
    pageIsOpen = true;
  }, 300);
}
```

Basically I have added this to the original function, but it does not work and it keeps injecting paragraphText0:

```
if (cards[0]) {
      openContentText.innerHTML = '<h1>'+card.children[2].textContent+'</h1>'+paragraphText0;
      openContentImage.src = card.children[1].src;
      } else if (cards[1]) {
        openContentText.innerHTML = '<h1>'+card.children[2].textContent+'</h1>'+paragraphText1;
        openContentImage.src = card.children[1].src;
      }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solution is not keeping good practices, as well as this piece of Codepen. You should definitely not put content that belongs to HTML via JS. However, I'm not into rewriting everything and this is the simplest way to make it work as you want it to do. I simply created 4 variables, that you need to put your content into. Then used `data-id` attribute in HTML to distinguish those cards. On click you pass `card` DOM element, we just need to access `data-id` => `var cardId = card.getAttribute('data-id')`. Then assign that digit (btw it is typeof string while accessed) to variable name => `eval('paragraphText' + cardId);`. Function `eval()` tries to run whatever you pass to it as piece of JS code so it gets string with name of variable for example `'paragraphText1'` and converts it into JS variable `paragraphText1`.

```js
// listing vars here so they're in the global scope
var cards, nCards, cover, openContent, openContentText, pageIsOpen = false,
    openContentImage, closeContent, windowWidth, windowHeight, currentCard;

// initiate the process
init();

function init() {
  resize();
  selectElements();
  attachListeners();
}

// select all the elements in the DOM that are going to be used
function selectElements() {
  cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card'),
  nCards = cards.length,
  cover = document.getElementById('cover'),
  openContent = document.getElementById('open-content'),
  openContentText = document.getElementById('open-content-text'),
  openContentImage = document.getElementById('open-content-image')
  closeContent = document.getElementById('close-content');
}

/* Attaching three event listeners here:
  - a click event listener for each card
  - a click event listener to the close button
  - a resize event listener on the window
*/
function attachListeners() {
  for (var i = 0; i < nCards; i++) {
    attachListenerToCard(i);
  }
  closeContent.addEventListener('click', onCloseClick);
  window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
}

function attachListenerToCard(i) {
  cards[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var card = getCardElement(e.target);
    onCardClick(card, i);
  })
}

/* When a card is clicked */
function onCardClick(card, i) {
  // set the current card
  currentCard = card;
  // add the 'clicked' class to the card, so it animates out
  currentCard.className += ' clicked';
  // animate the card 'cover' after a 500ms delay
  setTimeout(function() {animateCoverUp(currentCard)}, 500);
  // animate out the other cards
  animateOtherCards(currentCard, true);
  // add the open class to the page content
  openContent.className += ' open';
}

/*
* This effect is created by taking a separate 'cover' div, placing
* it in the same position as the clicked card, and animating it to
* become the background of the opened 'page'.
* It looks like the card itself is animating in to the background,
* but doing it this way is more performant (because the cover div is
* absolutely positioned and has no children), and there's just less
* having to deal with z-index and other elements in the card
*/
function animateCoverUp(card) {
  // get the position of the clicked card
  var cardPosition = card.getBoundingClientRect();
  // get the style of the clicked card
  var cardStyle = getComputedStyle(card);
  setCoverPosition(cardPosition);
  setCoverColor(cardStyle);
  scaleCoverToFillWindow(cardPosition);
  // update the content of the opened page
  var cardId = card.getAttribute('data-id')
  openContentText.innerHTML = '<h1>'+card.children[2].textContent+'</h1>'+ eval('paragraphText' + cardId);
  openContentImage.src = card.children[1].src;
  setTimeout(function() {
    // update the scroll position to 0 (so it is at the top of the 'opened' page)
    window.scroll(0, 0);
    // set page to open
    pageIsOpen = true;
  }, 300);
}

function animateCoverBack(card) {
  var cardPosition = card.getBoundingClientRect();
  // the original card may be in a different position, because of scrolling, so the cover position needs to be reset before scaling back down
  setCoverPosition(cardPosition);
  scaleCoverToFillWindow(cardPosition);
  // animate scale back to the card size and position
  cover.style.transform = 'scaleX('+1+') scaleY('+1+') translate3d('+(0)+'px, '+(0)+'px, 0px)';
  setTimeout(function() {
    // set content back to empty
    openContentText.innerHTML = '';
    openContentImage.src = '';
    // style the cover to 0x0 so it is hidden
    cover.style.width = '0px';
    cover.style.height = '0px';
    pageIsOpen = false;
    // remove the clicked class so the card animates back in
    currentCard.className = currentCard.className.replace(' clicked', '');
  }, 301);
}

function setCoverPosition(cardPosition) {
  // style the cover so it is in exactly the same position as the card
  cover.style.left = cardPosition.left + 'px';
  cover.style.top = cardPosition.top + 'px';
  cover.style.width = cardPosition.width + 'px';
  cover.style.height = cardPosition.height + 'px';
}

function setCoverColor(cardStyle) {
  // style the cover to be the same color as the card
  cover.style.backgroundColor = cardStyle.backgroundColor;
}

function scaleCoverToFillWindow(cardPosition) {
  // calculate the scale and position for the card to fill the page,
  var scaleX = windowWidth / cardPosition.width;
  var scaleY = windowHeight / cardPosition.height;
  var offsetX = (windowWidth / 2 - cardPosition.width / 2 - cardPosition.left) / scaleX;
  var offsetY = (windowHeight / 2 - cardPosition.height / 2 - cardPosition.top) / scaleY;
  // set the transform on the cover - it will animate because of the transition set on it in the CSS
  cover.style.transform = 'scaleX('+scaleX+') scaleY('+scaleY+') translate3d('+(offsetX)+'px, '+(offsetY)+'px, 0px)';
}

/* When the close is clicked */
function onCloseClick() {
  // remove the open class so the page content animates out
  openContent.className = openContent.className.replace(' open', '');
  // animate the cover back to the original position card and size
  animateCoverBack(currentCard);
  // animate in other cards
  animateOtherCards(currentCard, false);
}

function animateOtherCards(card, out) {
  var delay = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < nCards; i++) {
    // animate cards on a stagger, 1 each 100ms
    if (cards[i] === card) continue;
    if (out) animateOutCard(cards[i], delay);
    else animateInCard(cards[i], delay);
    delay += 100;
  }
}

// animations on individual cards (by adding/removing card names)
function animateOutCard(card, delay) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    card.className += ' out';
   }, delay);
}

function animateInCard(card, delay) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    card.className = card.className.replace(' out', '');
  }, delay);
}

// this function searches up the DOM tree until it reaches the card element that has been clicked
function getCardElement(el) {
  if (el.className.indexOf('card ') > -1) return el;
  else return getCardElement(el.parentElement);
}

// resize function - records the window width and height
function resize() {
  if (pageIsOpen) {
    // update position of cover
    var cardPosition = currentCard.getBoundingClientRect();
    setCoverPosition(cardPosition);
    scaleCoverToFillWindow(cardPosition);
  }
  windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
}

var paragraphText1 = '<p>Somebody once told me the world is gonna roll me. I ain\'t the sharpest tool in the shed. She was looking kind of dumb with her finger and her thumb in the shape of an "L" on her forehead. Well the years start coming and they don\'t stop coming. Fed to the rules and I hit the ground running. Didn\'t make sense not to live for fun. Your brain gets smart but your head gets dumb. So much to do, so much to see. So what\'s wrong with taking the back streets? You\'ll never know if you don\'t go. You\'ll never shine if you don\'t glow.</p><p>Hey now, you\'re an all-star, get your game on, go play. Hey now, you\'re a rock star, get the show on, get paid. And all that glitters is gold. Only shooting stars break the mold.</p><p>It\'s a cool place and they say it gets colder. You\'re bundled up now, wait till you get older. But the meteor men beg to differ. Judging by the hole in the satellite picture. The ice we skate is getting pretty thin. The water\'s getting warm so you might as well swim. My world\'s on fire, how about yours? That\'s the way I like it and I never get bored.</p>';

var paragraphText2 = '<h1>2</h1>';

var paragraphText3 ='<h1>3</h1>';

var paragraphText4 = '<h1>4</h1>';
```

```css
/* 
** Layout, Text & Colors 
*/

body {
  background: #150f21;
  font-size: 18px;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Cards */
.card-column {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 4%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column-1 {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.card {
  width: 92%;
  max-width: 340px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #EB5160;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
  left: -6px;
  top: -6px;
}

.card h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 190px 0px 100px 10px;
  width: 90%;
}

.card > img {
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6%;
  left: -6%;
}

.card-color-0 {
  background-color: #EB5160;
}

.card-color-1 {
  background-color: #8F3985;
}

.card-color-2 {
  background-color: #8DAA91;
}

.card-color-3 {
  background-color: #888DA7;
}

/* The cover (expanding background) */
.cover {
  position: fixed;
  background: #EB5160;
  z-index: 100;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

/* The open page content */
.open-content {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 110;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.open-content img {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.open-content .text {
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: -56%;
  padding: 60% 5% 5% 5%;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.open-content .text h1, .open-content .text p {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.close-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  top: 12px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.close-content span {
  background: #222;
  width: 30px;
  height: 6px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
}

.x-1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.x-2 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/* 
** Transitions
*/

.card {
  transition: opacity 200ms linear 320ms, transform 200ms ease-out 320ms;
}

.border {
  transition: opacity 200ms linear, transform 200ms ease-out;
}

.card img {
  transition: opacity 200ms linear 0ms, transform 200ms ease-in 0ms;
}

.card h1 {
  transform: translate3d(20%, 0px, 0px);  
  transition: opacity 200ms linear 120ms, transform 200ms ease-in 120ms;
}

/* Clicked card */
.card.clicked img {
  transform: translate3d(0px, -40px, 0px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.card.clicked .border {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.card.out, .card.out img {
  transform: translate3d(0px, -40px, 0px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.card.out h1, .card.clicked h1 {
  transform: translate3d(20%, -40px, 0px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.cover {
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.open-content {
  transition: opacity 200ms linear 0ms;
}

.open-content.open {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transition-delay: 1000ms;
}

/* 
** Media Queries
*/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .card-column {
    width: 90%;
  }
  
  .column-1 {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
  
  .open-content img {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--
  Please note: this code is in no way ready to be used as is in production on your website. It will need to be adapted to be cross browser compliant & accessible. I just wanted to share how one might go about this effect with CSS & JS and no other dependencies
-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-column column-0">
    <div class="card card-color-0" data-id="1">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53148/deathtostock-00.jpg" />
      <h1>Hey now, you're an allstar</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-color-2" data-id="2">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53148/deathtostock-02.jpg" />
      <h1>Hey now, you're a rock star</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-column column-1">
    <div class="card card-color-1" data-id="3">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53148/deathtostock-01.jpg" />
      <h1>Get your game on, go play</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-color-3" data-id="4">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53148/deathtostock-03.jpg" />
      <h1>Get the show on, get paid</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cover" class="cover"></div>

<div id="open-content" class="open-content">
  <a href="#" id="close-content" class="close-content"><span class="x-1"></span><span class="x-2"></span></a>
  <img id="open-content-image" src="" />
  <div class="text" id="open-content-text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks indeed! That fixed it. I will look into more compliant way of doing it also

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the text in a global variable `paragraphText`, create a function that returns the text, depending on the index of the card that was clicked:

```
function getFullText(cardIndex) {
  switch (cardIndex) {
    case 0:
      return (
        "Somebody once told me the world is gonna roll me. " +
        "I ain't the sharpest tool in the shed. " +
        "She was looking kind of dumb with her finger and her thumb. " +
        'In the shape of an "L" on her forehead.'
      );
    case 1:
      return (
        "Well the years start coming and they don't stop coming. " +
        "Fed to the rules and I hit the ground running. " +
        "Didn't make sense not to live for fun. " +
        "Your brain gets smart but your head gets dumb."
      );
    case 2:
      return (
        "So much to do, so much to see. " +
        "So what's wrong with taking the back streets? " +
        "You'll never know if you don't go. " +
        "You'll never shine if you don't glow."
      );
    case 3:
      return (
        "It's a cool place and they say it gets colder. " +
        "You're bundled up now, wait till you get older. " +
        "But the meteor men beg to differ. " +
        "Judging by the hole in the satellite picture."
      );
    default:
      throw new Error("unknown card index", cardIndex);
  }
}
```

The argument `cardIndex` is the zero-based number of the card that was clicked.

Call this function from `onCardClick` and pass the result to `animateCoverUp`, like this:

```
function onCardClick(card, i) {
  var fullText = getFullText(i);
  // set the current card
  currentCard = card;
  // add the 'clicked' class to the card, so it animates out
  currentCard.className += " clicked";
  // animate the card 'cover' after a 500ms delay
  // pass the index
  setTimeout(function() {
    animateCoverUp(currentCard, fullText);
  }, 500);
  // animate out the other cards
  animateOtherCards(currentCard, true);
  // add the open class to the page content
  openContent.className += " open";
}
```

Finally, in `animateCoverUp`, use the second argument, the full text, instead of the global variable `paragraphText` (which you can delete):

```
function animateCoverUp(card, fullText) {
  // get the position of the clicked card
  var cardPosition = card.getBoundingClientRect();
  // get the style of the clicked card
  var cardStyle = getComputedStyle(card);
  setCoverPosition(cardPosition);
  setCoverColor(cardStyle);
  scaleCoverToFillWindow(cardPosition);
  // update the content of the opened page
  openContentText.innerHTML =
    "<h1>" + card.children[2].textContent + "</h1>" + fullText;
  openContentImage.src = card.children[1].src;
  setTimeout(function() {
    // update the scroll position to 0 (so it is at the top of the 'opened' page)
    window.scroll(0, 0);
    // set page to open
    pageIsOpen = true;
  }, 300);
}
```

Here is a working version of the code pen:

https://codepen.io/pahund/pen/PXXwRG

Comment: Many thanks... although the answer above fixed it I will probably look into a more compliant way of doing this

Comment: Like the author pointed out, the accepted answer ignores best practices (e.g. “don't use eval”, “avoid global variables”). Just sayin' ‍♂️

Comment: I completely agree. Voted up your answer as you definitely put more effort into it :)

Comment: An even better solution would be to store the full text in the HTML code in a hidden div, but that would require a lot more refactoring of the code, and it's Sunday, so I'll resist spending more time on it 